# ListView Load element with animation one by one

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a simple ListView here with RotationAnimation when the listview is loaded. Basically the listview I have has pre defined model or list elements. I want to load each element with the RotationAnimation that I have one by one. For example, first element is displayed with animation and after few milliseconds (0.5ms) the next element will be displayed with animation. What I currently have right now is the whole listview will be displayed with animation including all the elements already. Is there anyway to do what I want?

This is what I currently have where the whole listview is displayed with animation

```
ListView {
    width: 240; height: 320
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement{
            name:"One"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Two"
        }
        ListElement{
            name:"Three"
        }
    }
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 30
        border.width: 1
        color: "Transparent"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: name
        }
        Component.onCompleted: seqAnim.start();
                transform: Rotation { id:rotate; origin.x: width; origin.y: height; axis { x: 0.3; y: 1; z: 0 } angle: 0}
                SequentialAnimation {
                            id: seqAnim
                            running: false
                            RotationAnimation { target: rotate; from: 180; to: 0; duration: 3000; easing.type: Easing.OutBack; property: "angle" }
                        }

    }
}
```

What I want is the ListElements are displayed one by one entering from left to right

Answer (score 2):

With a static model like you used, you will get all elements animated since that happens in the delegate.

On the other hand, with a dynamic model (where elements are added along the way), will let you get animation for each element individually.

You need to manage (suitably) how model elements are added to the model based on your practical model.

An example to demonstrate the concept is by adding model elements with a timer, sine you mentioned you want a period between the animations ...

```
ListModel {
    id:lModel
    ListElement{
        name:"One"
    }
}
Timer {
    property int indexer: 0
    id:timer
    interval: 1000 ;running: true; repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        if(indexer === 0)
            lModel.append({name:"Two"})
        else if (indexer === 1)
            lModel.append({name:"Three"})
        else timer.stop()
        indexer++
    }
}

ListView {
    width: 240; height: 320
    model: lModel
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 30
        border.width: 1
        color: "Transparent"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: name
        }
        Component.onCompleted: seqAnim.start();
        transform: Rotation { id:rotate; origin.x: width; origin.y: height; axis { x: 0.3; y: 1; z: 0 } angle: 0}
        SequentialAnimation {
            id: seqAnim
            running: false
            RotationAnimation { target: rotate; from: 180; to: 0; duration: 3000; easing.type: Easing.OutBack; property: "angle" }
        }

    }
}
```